# Successive Ajax calls in Javascript For Loop - Playlist

Tags: javascript, ajax, for-loop, playlist

Please Help!! I'm seeing a lot of mixed results when I search for this, none of them which apply here. My goal is basically to turn a randomly and dynamically populated list of songs into a playlist, so that each song plays one after the other, and the iframe for youtube or soundcloud is ajaxed in in sequence.

I have a simple list of songs that is populated from the youtube and soundcloud api's, which is output to an unordered list. As each song in the list is loaded into the browser its anchor tag is given an id.

```
//List Item
echo "<a id=\"" . $i . "\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"play_clicked('youtube',".$i.",".$song_count.")\">
                            <li class = \"song\">";
```

The first song in the list gets id 0, the second, 1 and so on. The media id of each song is also "pushed" onto a javascript array one at a time as they load, so that the id of the song's anchor tag corresponds to the key in the array where the song's media id is held.

```
echo 
'<script type="text/javascript">

track_id_array.push("'.$vid_id.'");

</script>';
```

I've created a javascript function that is called when a song is clicked:

```
function play_clicked(api_type,clicked_key,song_count)
```

The function receives parameters for api type - soundcloud or youtube, the anchor id, or array key where the clicked media id is held, and then how many songs are in the list. There is a for loop to iterate through the array of media ids:

```
for (var i=clicked_key; i<=song_count; i++){
```

So I am starting the loop at whatever the id of the clicked song was, and the goal is to continue to iterate through the songs that follow after the clicked song. First I check if the media id exists in the array:

```
if(window.track_id_array[i])
```

If this exists, it should hold the media's id - example youtube id - 6_8ZZtL6qmM. Then I check whether it is a soundcloud or youtube song, and depending on which, I send the media id with ajax to a php script that will embed the id into the html5 iframe embed widget for either soundcloud or youtube, something like this:

```
$vid_id = $_GET[id];

//Youtube player embed
echo '<iframe width="498" height="280" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$vid_id. '?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
';
```

and then I return this html to a div inside my main page, and the song will play in the corresponding widget. The way I had imagined accomplishing my goal of a playlist is to start with the clicked song's id/key in the loop, retrieve the media id for that key from the array, check the api type, make the proper ajax call, set a timeout for the length of the song, and then have the loop continue to the next key in the array after the song was finished playing, so that it would start the process over with the next song in the list, or id in the array.

Javascript is really not my strong suit and I hate that I have to use client-side code for this. My question is, is the method I described here possible, or am I going about this the wrong way? I only want to make the ajax calls one after the other in the loop, so they won't be happening at the same time. Here is my whole function and I am getting some weird results. It plays the last song in the list and skips over all others. Any explanation for maybe why? Again I am really not great with javascript, and help is MUCH appreciated!!

```
//play clicked track and those following
function play_clicked(api_type,clicked_key,song_count){

function showPlayTrack() {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xhr.status == 200) {
                        var outLink = xhr.responseText;
                    }
                    else {
                        var outLink = "There was a problem with the request" + xhr.status;
                    }
                    }
                    var vis = parent.document.getElementById("play_content");

                    vis.innerHTML = outLink;

                    setTimeout(300000);
}   


for (var i=clicked_key;i<=song_count;i++){

    if(window.track_id_array[i]){

        if(api_type == "scloud"){

                var soundcloud_id = window.track_id_array[i];

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else {
                    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                        try {
                            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        }
                        catch (e) { 
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (xhr) {
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = showPlayTrack;
                    xhr.open("GET", "getsoundcloud.php?streamurl="+soundcloud_id, true);


                }
                else {
                    alert("Sorry, but I could't create an XMLHttpRequest");
                }



        }else if (api_type == "youtube"){


            var vid_id = window.track_id_array[i];

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else {
                    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                        try {
                            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        }
                        catch (e) { 
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (xhr) {
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = showPlayTrack;
                    xhr.open("GET", "getyoutube.php?streamurl="+vid_id, true);
                    xhr.send(null);

                }
                else {
                    alert("Sorry, but I could't create an XMLHttpRequest");
                }

        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I solved the problem by using recursive function calls. On click I call the play function, which reads the media id, checks the api type, increments the key and calls the ajax to get the iframe. The success function for the ajax then returns the iframe to the appropriate div, waits the length of the song and then calls the initial play function again with the incremented key as the param. Theres still some small things to work out, like adding or subtracting time if the user seeks in the media, but for the most part this is a great playlist solution!